# PHP's APC analogue for Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

PHP has different opcode caches like APC, Zend Optimizer to cache the code and dramatically speed things up. Does Ruby have something similar?

Answer (score 4):

The default Ruby 1.9.x is based on a bytecode VM, in addition you have ruby implementations based on the Java Virtual Machine ([JRuby](http://www.jruby.org/)) and LLVM ([Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) and [MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/)). These will all do just-in-time compilation and other optimizations you'd expect from a modern VM.

Answer (score 1):

Default production settings in Rails is:

```
config.cache_classes = true
```

which mean that code isn't reloaded after requests, therefore it's cached in memory.

Comment: So if I understood right, in Ruby, code caching problem solved in a more elegant way than in PHP? I mean, in PHP you install third party cache, but Ruby has this feature built-in, am I right?

Comment: Timus: Depending on the implementation, but in Ruby 1.9 and later or with MacRuby, JRuby etc it's built right into the implementation. They all use different VM's though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as MRI is concerned, experimental bytecode caching has been [released](http://rimuru.lunanet.gr.jp/blog/cruby-bytecode-cache-is-experimentally-released) with Ruby 2.3.

> All you need to do to make this feature enabled is just to require
>   'yomikomu' rubygem and set some environmental variables introduced at
>   here as you can find two export commands in the example above.
>
> It may look a bit magical why VM-level bytecode cache is enabled only
>   by requiring 'yomikomu' rubygem. Koichi described about this at his
>   ticket.

Here is a quick benchmark result of current bytecode cache implementation. I used 'bundle version' command with benchmark-ips on Ubuntu machine. Source

The post also provides some benchmarks for this newly released functionality:

```
$ ruby measure.rb
Comparison:
        yomikomu(fs):        5.0 i/s
         yomikomanai:        3.6 i/s - 1.40x slower
```

Other ruby implementations might be able to take advantage of the platform native optimizations - eg. JRuby benefits from the performance benefits of JVM JIT.